# How to correct bootstrap3 and tooltip: placement display error?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this nasty display on some elements with bootstrap3
[image]

**the black triangle is in the MIDDLE of the tooltip.**

My placement is set to "auto"

and even removing all my css and all js (keeping only bootstrap and css) I have this problem

```
// I just keep this to test and still have problem
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Here is the way it is called (in the footer.php)

```
(function() {
    bootbox.setDefaults({ locale: "en"});
    $('[title]').tooltip({
        placement:"auto"
    });
```

Here is the FULL Page

```
<!doctype html>
<html >
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>    
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">    
</head>    
<body>    
            <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
              <label title="Main-Stage" class="btn btn-default  active" >
                <input type="radio"  name="options" checked >Main-Stage
                </label>
              <label title="Chat with DJ" class="btn btn-default"  >
                <input type="radio" name="options" > DJ 
              </label>
              <label title="Chat with Manager"  class="btn btn-default">
                <input type="radio" name="options" > Manager     
              </label>
            </div>

<script>

(function() {
    $('[title]').tooltip({
        placement:"auto"
    });

})();   

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

FIDDLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/a279b885/

Comment: `When "auto" value is specified, it will dynamically reorient the tooltip.

For example, if placement value is "auto top", the tooltip will display on the top when possible, otherwise it will display on the bottom.`

Comment: your screenshot obviously shows custom CSS, i doubt this is a bootstrap error.

Comment: Agree with @NDM. To be able to solve this, we must see the markup and all added CSS. Can it be reproduced in a fiddle?

Comment: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a279b885/

Comment: Sounds like you're encountering https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/14197

Comment: any idea how to solve it ?